# Find a Fourier transform of $|\sin(x)|$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $f(x) = |\sin(x)|$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is a corresponding functional in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$. Find its Fourier transform. My attempt:
$$\hat{F}(\phi) =  F(\hat{\phi}) = \int_\limits{\mathbb{R}}|\sin(x)|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy}\phi(y)dy\right)dx = $$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int\limits_{2\pi k}^{2\pi k+\pi}\sin(x)\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy}\phi(y)dydx - \int\limits_{2\pi k + \pi}^{2\pi k+2\pi}\sin(x)\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy}\phi(y)dydx\right) = $$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y)\int\limits_{2\pi k}^{2\pi k+\pi} e^{-ixy}\sin(x)dxdy - \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y)\int\limits_{2\pi k + \pi}^{2\pi k+2\pi} e^{-ixy}\sin(x)dxdy\right) = $$
$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y) \frac{-2e^{-iy(2\pi k + \pi)} - e^{-2iy\pi k}- e^{-iy(2\pi k+2\pi)}}{y^2-1}dy = $$
$$= -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(y)\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-iy(2\pi k + \pi)} + e^{-2iy\pi k}}{y^2-1}\right)dy$$
Hence, $\hat{F}$ is a corresponding functional to $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ix(2\pi k + \pi)} + e^{-2ix\pi k}}{x^2-1}$. Clearly, this is not the right answer, this function is not continuous at $x=1$.

I use Fubini theorem to swap the integrals but not sure if it's correct here. Could you please tell me what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you think the answer should be continuous at $1$?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy I also tried to use the representation $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$, also considering the integrals on the segments

Comment: @NinadMunshi it should belong $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, shouldn't it?

Comment: That's not right, the Fourier transform should be in $\mathcal{S}'(\Bbb{R})$, too

Comment: @NinadMunshi the functional $\hat{F}$ should be in $\mathcal{S}'$, of course. I meant that the function corresponding to this functional belong to $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Who said that the functional would have a corresponding function? Your assumptions are off base here. As a sidenote, it's not true that $F\mapsto \int F(\cdot) \in \mathcal{S}'(\Bbb{R})$ means that $F$ is Schwartz, since tempered distributions are those that which grow, at most, polynomially toward infinity (heuristically speaking). Which is a superset of the Schwartz functions.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for the clarification. So, do you think that my answer may be correct?

Comment: Not as written, without caveats? I'm sorry I can't be more clear since I haven't computed this myself, but you should consider if this contains point masses, or their derivatives.

Answer (score 3):

First, notice that $|\sin x|$ is a periodic function. So you should expect its Fourier transform to be a sum of Dirac deltas (exercise left to you!).

But instead of computing that Fourier transform, let's first look at that of $\text{sgn}(\sin x)$. Again $\text{sgn}(\sin x)$ is periodic and its Fourier series is easy to compute. Indeed,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \text{sgn}(\sin x) e^{inx}dx = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{4i}{n} & \text{if $n$ is odd}\\
0 & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Thus the Fourier series in question is
$$\text{sgn}(\sin x) = -\frac {2i} \pi \sum_{n\geq 1 \text{ odd}} \frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}n=-\frac {2i} \pi \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{e^{(2m+1)ix}-e^{-(2m+1)ix}}{2m+1}$$
And the Fourier transform of that function is
$$\widehat {\text{sgn}(\sin)}(\omega) = -4i \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{\delta(\omega - (2m+1))-\delta(\omega +(2m+1))}{2m+1}\tag{1}$$
We also know that
$$\widehat {\sin}(\omega) = \frac{\delta(\omega-1)-\delta(\omega+1)}{2i}\tag{2}$$

And because $|\sin x|=\sin(x) \cdot\text{sgn}(\sin x)$, you can deduce the Fourier transform of $|\sin x|$ by taking the convolution of the fourier transforms:

$$
\widehat{|\sin|}(\omega) = \frac 1 {2\pi} \widehat {\sin}\ast \widehat {\text{sgn}(\sin)}(\omega)$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, can you finish?

Comment: +1 This is beautiful, especially since Wolfram Alpha gave up on this

Comment: Thank you. Doing my best :)

Comment: @StefanLafon grateful for the help